# take row-wise means of two groups containing some overlapping columns dplyr tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling, rowwise

I have a df of x,y coords, and a variable through a bunch of years. I am trying to group years and take the means of each group still in each x/y coordinate. Sometimes these groups contain some of the same years and I can not figure out how to do it.  (Like, compare the 2000-2005 average in each coordinate point to to the 2003-2008 average). Feels like this shouldn't be difficult, but I'm coding myself in circles. I also need it to be programmatic because the groups of years will change.

I would prefer to keep this in tidyverse syntax.

reprex:

```
set.seed(0)
# make df
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:50,
  y = 201:250,
  var1999 = sample(c(10:50,NA),50,replace = T), # there may be occasionally NAs as well
  var2000 = sample(c(100:50,NA),50,replace = T),
  var2001 = sample(c(100:500,NA),50,replace = T),
  var2002 = sample(c(100:500,NA),50,replace = T),
  var2003 = sample(c(100:500,NA),50,replace = T),
  var2004 = sample(c(100:200,NA),50,replace = T)
)

year_group1 <- c(1999:2002)
year_group2 <- c(2002:2004) # note that 2002 will be in both groups

# desired output: (ignore the numbers, they are made up)
    x   y   mean_year_group1  mean_year_group2    delta 
1   1  201      184.5               324              20
2   2  202      155.9               118              43
3   3  203      162.3               470              21
4   4  204      144.1               496              23
5   5  205      183.2               405              55
```

So far, I've tried selecting the year_group1 columns, then taking a mean of them (and even that will not work, confusingly.), and I was going to just do them in two different sets, then merge the means back together and find the change between them. I'm sure some tidyverse expert out there has a better way.

Here's what didn't work:

```
df %>%
  select(x,y, paste0("var",year_group1)) %>%
  mutate( mean = mean(c(var1999, var2000, var2001, var2002)))

df %>%
  select(x,y, paste0("var",year_group1)) %>%
  dplyr::rename_at(vars(contains("var",ignore.case = F)), list(~ paste0("yeargroup1", .))) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(contains("year1")))
```

thanks!

Comment: fixed it, thank you

Comment: Do you have more than two groups i.e. around 10 or 20 groups?

Answer (score 0):

We could use `select` to subset the data (as the column names are not exactly matching, use `matches` or can `paste` the 'var' as prefix and then wrap it in `all_of` within `select`) and `transmute` with the `rowMeans` of each groups

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   transmute(x, y,
    mean_year_group1 = rowMeans(select(., 
       matches(str_c(year_group1, collapse="|"))), na.rm = TRUE), 
   mean_year_group2 = rowMeans(select(., matches(str_c(year_group2, 
          collapse="|"))), na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

or using `collapse`, with rowwise operations using `dapply` and `fmean`

```
library(collapse)
yr_gr1 <- paste0('var', year_group1)
yr_gr2 <- paste0('var', year_group2)
mean1grp <- df %>%
     get_vars(yr_gr1) %>%
      dapply(FUN = fmean, MARGIN = 1)
mean2grp <- df %>%
 get_vars(yr_gr2) %>% 
 dapply(FUN = fmean, MARGIN = 1)
df %>% 
   slt(x, y) %>%
   ftransform(mean_year_group1 = mean1grp, 
              mean_year_group2 = mean2grp)
```

---

In the OP's code for `mean`, if we want to use it, then do a `rowwise` (but it is inefficient)

```
df %>%
  select(x,y, paste0("var",year_group1)) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate( mean = mean(c(var1999, var2000, var2001, var2002))) %>%
  ungroup
```